# How to create HATEOAS Resource Link to remote service method?

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-hateoas

The scenario looks like that:

- eureka server and two other services (spring-boot-apps) are running
- two micro services (A and B) are registered in eureka server
- both services provides REST HATEOAS endpoint
- app 'A' provides a service method 'x' which response message should contains a link to a remote REST endpoint 'y' from a service 'B'

My idea was to use: DynamicServiceInstanceProvider and Traverson to finally get a Link object.

```
DynamicServiceInstanceProvider provider = new DynamicServiceInstanceProvider(discoveryClient, "B");
Traverson traverson = new Traverson(provider.getUri(), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
Link link = traverson.follow("y").asTemplatedLink();
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work at all :/ What I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to obtain a link to a remote endpoint?

Comment: "doesn't work at all' isn't really helpful. What happens? What versions are you using? What is your configuration? Have you verified that "B" is registered in eureka? Please provide more information.

Comment: @spencergibb As I described "two microservices are registered in eureka", so B is registered :) In short. I don't understand how to use Traverson correctly. In my sandbox project I stoped using it -> https://github.com/kjkrol/kotlin4fun-eshop-app In this case I would like to create a Link to a remote REST method (and I did it, but without Tracerson).